# Unable to build or update project since Cordova Cli v4.3.0 Update

Tags: ios, cordova, build

Since, update to cordova cli v4.3.0, I'm unable to to run "cordova platform update" or "cordova build".
Although, "cordova compile" works fine.
The error is as follows:

```
could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cordova build ios
could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix your error ? Got the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Cordova was the project initially created in? It may be due to compatibility issue if the project was created in an older version of Cordova